# My code not run in "sequence"

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I use an API in my project (`Coding4Fun.Toolkit`) for shows messageBox with textbox inside. So, when I call the `MessagePrompt` code, it doesn't run at the right time.

```
private void holdListAdd(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs)
{
    var dc = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
    Fields fi = (Fields)dc;

    if (List2.Items.Contains(fi))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Esse item já foi adicionado!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessagePrompt messagePrompt = new MessagePrompt();

        messagePrompt.Body = new BodyUserControl();
        messagePrompt.Show();

        IsolatedStorageSettings iso = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (iso.TryGetValue<string>("isoQuantity", out retornaNome))
        {
            qtd = retornaNome;
        }
        fi.Quantity = qtd;

        List2.Items.Add(fi);
        MessageBox.Show("Item Adicionado com sucesso!");
    }
```

note that in `holdListAdd`, the last code is `List2.Items.Add(fi);`, but it is run before `MessagePrompt`. Why?

BodyUserControl.xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"  Margin="0,0,0,10">
    <Grid Height="157">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="55,0,51,86" Width="374">
            <Run Text="       "/>
            <Run Text="Digite a quantidade a adicionar:"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="Quantity" Margin="103,68,222,17"/>
        <Button Content="Adicionar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="addQuantity" Click="addQuantity_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

BodyUserControl.cs:

```
public partial class BodyUserControl : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public BodyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addQuantity_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings iso = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        {
            if (iso.Contains("isoQuantity"))
            {
                iso["isoQuantity"] = Quantity.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                iso.Add("isoQuantity", Quantity.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain "Run Before" and what is the problem you are facing due to this ?

Comment: I need add one product from `ListBox1` to `ListBox2`. The `MessagePrompt` should request the quantity of items. My problem is: the item is add before request quantity.

Comment: ans is right just use that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your code continues while the `MessagePrompt` is shown. If you want to do something after the `MessagePrompt` has been completed you'll have to assing a event handler to `MessagePrompt.Completed`. Something like

```
messagePrompt.Completed += messagePrompt_Completed;
messagePrompt.Show();

void messagePrompt_Completed(object sender, PopUpEventArgs<object, PopUpResult> e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings iso = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (iso.TryGetValue<string>("isoQuantity", out retornaNome))
    {
        qtd = retornaNome;
    }
    fi.Quantity = qtd;

    List2.Items.Add(fi);
    MessageBox.Show("Item Adicionado com sucesso!");
};
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but this issue show: No overload for 'messagePrompt_Completed' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: Please update the question with the new code. It is hard to tell what's wrong. By the way, I said: something like... My code won't work without further modifications. Especially the `fi.Quantity` is problematic because `fi` isn't declared within the scope of the event handler. But I guess you can fix that yourself.